# Update the value when the row already exists

Tags: db2, merge, upsert, db2-10.5

I have table 'A' in schema 'USER'. There are three columns in this table.
below are the names of the columns:

- id (primary key)
- name
- age

I want to insert a row in this table, but if the row is already present (with same id) then the name and age should be updated instead of giving error sqlcode -803.

Is there any way to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments on the question, [`MERGE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_merge.dita) is the answer you are looking for.

Check out this great blog as well:

[`MERGE` statement explained](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/merge?lang=en) by Serge Rielau (瑞赛奇) and Rick Swagerman.

It will look somewhat like this for your case:

```
MERGE INTO <tab> AS ...
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE ...
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT...
```